# How can I use Explorer in Powershell to select a file to be processed within my Powershell script

Tags: powershell, filepicker, fileopendialog

I wrote a script in which I use a static file for example "datainput.csv"

I would like to launch an explorer session within my script to allow the user to pick a file and then be able to grab the file name within the script to process it.

I have no clue where to start..

I know how to launch Explorer, but not grab the file name.. Right now explorer launches the file external to my script.

Comment: See https://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-create-an-open-file-folder-dialog-box-with-powershell/

Comment: The linked question is about batch files, but the accepted answer also has PowerShell code. In short: Use WinForms' [`System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog) class